# VHDL - unconnected components in top module

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I am working on a project and I'm failing to connect the components in the top module.
I just can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Besides not being able to see the components in the RTL schematic, I get some warnings:

```
WARNING:Xst:1290 - Hierarchical block <u0> is unconnected in block <TOP>.
   It will be removed from the design.
WARNING:Xst:1290 - Hierarchical block <u1> is unconnected in block <TOP>.
   It will be removed from the design.

WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <u1/calc_deb> of sequential type is unconnected in block <TOP>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <u1/flipflops_1> of sequential type is unconnected in block <TOP>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <u1/flipflops_0> of sequential type is unconnected in block <TOP>.
```

So here is the implementation of the top module:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


entity TOP is
port(
    calc: in std_logic;
    OP: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    inValue: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    clk: in std_logic
    );
end TOP;

architecture Behavioral of TOP is

component alu port(
        OP : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
      inValue : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
      regValue : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
      result: out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
      clk : in  STD_LOGIC
        );
end component;

component debouncer port(
    calc : in  STD_LOGIC;
    calc_deb : out  STD_LOGIC;
    clk: in std_logic
);  
end component;

signal calc_debaux: std_logic;
signal regValueaux: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal resultaux: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
--signal OP: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
--signal OP: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);


begin

u0: alu port map(OP => OP,  inValue=>inValue,   regValue=>regValueaux,  result=>resultaux, clk=>clk);

u1: debouncer PORT MAP(calc=>calc, alc_deb=>calc_debaux, clk=>clk);

end Behavioral;
```

And here are the two entities that I'm instantiating in the top module:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity ALU is
    Port ( OP : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
           inValue : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
           regValue : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
           result: out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC
              );
end ALU;

architecture archi of alu is

signal res_temp: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
signal aux1, aux2: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

begin

aux1 <= ('0' & inValue);
aux2 <= ('0' & regValue);
result <= res_temp; 

process (inValue, OP)
begin
        case OP is
            when "00" =>
                res_temp <=  (aux1) + (aux2) ;
            when "01" =>
                res_temp <= aux1 - aux2; 
            when "10" =>
                res_temp <= (inValue and regValue);
            when others =>
                res_temp <= '0' & (regValue(0) & regValue(3 downto 1));   
        end case;
end process;
end archi ; 

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


entity debouncer is
    Port ( calc : in  STD_LOGIC;
           calc_deb : out  STD_LOGIC;
              clk: in std_logic);
end debouncer;

architecture Behavioral of debouncer is
  SIGNAL flipflops   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0); --input flip flops
  SIGNAL counter_set : STD_LOGIC;                    --sync reset to zero
  SIGNAL counter_out : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0'); --counter output
BEGIN

  counter_set <= flipflops(0) xor flipflops(1);   --determine when to start/reset counter

  PROCESS(clk)
  BEGIN
    IF(clk'EVENT and clk = '1') THEN
      flipflops(0) <= calc;
      flipflops(1) <= flipflops(0);
      If(counter_set = '1') THEN                  --reset counter because input is changing
        counter_out <= (OTHERS => '0');
      ELSIF(counter_out(8) = '0') THEN --stable input time is not yet met
        counter_out <= counter_out + 1;
      ELSE                                        --stable input time is met
        calc_deb <= flipflops(1);
      END IF;    
    END IF;
  END PROCESS;

end Behavioral;
```

I also get some more warnings:

```
Synthesizing Unit <TOP>.
    Related source file is "D:/Mestrado/1o ano/1o semestre/PSD/Projectos/andgates/TOP.vhd".
WARNING:Xst:646 - Signal <resultaux> is assigned but never used. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:653 - Signal <regValueaux> is used but never assigned. This sourceless signal will be automatically connected to value 0000.
WARNING:Xst:646 - Signal <calc_debaux> is assigned but never used. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process.
Unit <TOP> synthesized.
```

I have spend a huge time in this (this is part of a bigger project, I'm just trying to restart by going piece by piece to facilitate troubleshooting) and I am now clueless. :(

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `u1: debouncer PORT MAP(calc=>calc, alc_deb=>calc_debaux, clk=>clk);` should be `u1: debouncer PORT MAP(calc=>calc, calc_deb=>calc_debaux, clk=>clk);` (The formal `alc_deb` in the association list should be `calc_deb`).  The collective VHDL design specifications analyzes and elaborate after fixing that.

Comment: You can search on Stackoverflow for [Posts containing 'warning:xst:1290'](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvhdl%5DWARNING%3AXst%3A1290).  There's also Google and specifically Xilinx's support site.  Are `alu` and `debouncer` in your project?

Comment: Also see [WARNING:Xst:1290 ](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/WARNING-Xst-1290-Hierarchical-block-is-unconnected-in-block-lt/td-p/126600) on the Xilinx Support web site.

Comment: Hi David,
thank you! But after fixing that, I get the exact same warnings posted here in the synthesis report. As you may have noticed, I am fairly new to VHDL and I'm failing to understand the meaning of these warnings.
Note that I'm not going to build stimulus file to simulate. Rather, I'll be running the project on a spartan-3e.

Comment: Hi David, I didn't notice your other 2 comments. I'll check those links and get back to you. And yes, debouncer and ALU are in my project under the top module "tree"

Comment: Note `top` has no output.  Everything will get eaten.

Answer (score 0):

Your top level entity, `TOP`, does not seem to have any output pins. ISE is pretty smart when it comes to trying save FPGA resources during synthesis. Any logic that is not used somehow to determine the state of an output pin in the top level entity will be synthesised away. I'm guessing that it thinks your entire design is (for lack of better word) useless as none of it is used to drive an output pin of `TOP`.

Try actually connecting your `resultaux` and/or `calc_debaux` output signals to output ports of `TOP` itself. Hopefully that clears up your warnings.

Comment: Check out the comment "Note `top` has no output. Everything will get eaten" on the question itself.  The questioner had noted earlier in an answer that he had gotten it to work.  He withdrew the answer because it wasn't useful (He hadn't explained what was wrong).

Comment: You are correct @DavidKoontz. Sorry I did not see your final comment. As long as he got things working I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems in your code include:

- Typo in port name `alc_deb` should be `calc_deb` in instantiation of u1. This is a hard error.
- Incomplete sensitivity list for `process (inValue, OP)`. Should be: `process (inValue, OP, aux1, aux2, regValue)`
- `clk` is not used in entity `ALU`
- None of the signals in `TOP` are ever read. (Rhis is related to the fact that TOP does not have output ports.)
- Bonus (pet peeve): replace `IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL` with `IEEE.NUMERIC_STD`. The former is not standardized and has multiple problems.